# Data label misalignment in 3D Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I’m using 3D Highcharts. Data labels works fine for 2D charts but I’m  facing issue with data label positioning  after 3D projection.I’ve attached the screenshot and code snippet here for your reference.

Expected behaviour:
Data labels should be properly positioned appropriate to x-axis values.It should not go out of chart for extremely low values of series data.

Actual behaviour:

[image]

```
options3d = {
        enabled: true,
        alpha: 15,
        beta: 15,
        depth: 40
    };
```

Description:
    Consider the above screenshot having series data=[1,37,790,1962] and [4,2130,342,1302].Placement of datalabels for data ‘1’ and ‘1302’ are not aligned properly.We can achieve proper alignment of datalabels by changing alpha and beta values.But I’m looking for a proper fix that will allow me to achieve this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The reported issue on Highcharts repo: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5508. As you can see, there is no ETA for this issue yet. Please continue on the mentioned thread.